# DBSCAN Clustering Unlike Names Together (Python)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, dbscan

I am using TF-IDF and DBSCAN to cluster similar human names in a database. The goal of the project is to be able to cluster together names that belong to the same person but may not necessarily be formatted or spelt the same. For example, John Smith can be also be labeled in the database as J. Smith or Smith, John. Ideally the model would be able to cluster these instances together.

The dataset I'm working with has over 250K records. I understand that DBSCAN will label records that are noise as `-1`. However, the model is also producing an additional cluster that almost always has around 200K records in it and the vast majority of the records within seem like they should be in their own individual clusters. Is there a reason why this may be happening? I'm considering running another model on this large cluster to see what happens.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First off, DBSCAN is a reasonable method for supervised clustering when the amount of clusters you have is unknown.

You need to pass a matrix of distances for every string you are clustering upon. What [string similarity metric](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/string-similarity-edit-distance) you use is your choice. Here is an example with Levenstein distance where `names` is a list or array of your strings for clustering:

```
import Levenshtein as Lev
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

lev_similarity = 1 * np.array([[Lev.distance(v1, v2) for v1 in names] for v2 in names])
dbscan = DBSCAN(eps=5, min_samples=1)
dbscan.fit(lev_similarity)
```

Because we are using lev distance, eps will be the number of substitutions to turn one string into the other. Tune it for your use case. The biggest concern being longer names being shortened (`'malala yousafzai'` vs `'malala y.'` is more substitutions than `'jane doe'` to `'jane d.'`)

My assumption as to why your current code has most of your dataset clustered: your `eps` value is tuned too high.

Answer (score 0):

You called it 'DBSCAN', and I know what you're talking about because I'm doing this at work right now, but your descriptions sounds much more like fuzzy matching. Check out the link below and see if that helps you get to your end game.

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/matching-messy-pandas-columns-with-fuzzywuzzy-4adda6c7994f

Also, below is a link to a canonical example of DBSCAN, but again, I don't think that's what you actually want to do.

https://towardsdatascience.com/dbscan-clustering-for-data-shapes-k-means-cant-handle-well-in-python-6be89af4e6ea